# Annual is to yearly as _____ is to monthly

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy, recurring-events

A more formal word for *yearly* would be *annual*.

> I pay my school loans annually
>
> I pay my rent check monthly or _____.

What is the equivalent of “annual” for “monthly"?

Comment: I think there is some confusion here because you are asking for the *-ual* version of the word—but your example sentences bely that by using a *-ually* form. Based on your original title and the final sentence in your question, it seems that your examples are misleading rather than clarifying. You should really be using *I pay my school's* ***annual*** *loan* and *I pay my apartment's ___ rent (✘ monthly)*.

Comment: Caleb, I don't think there is another word for "monthly". Just because one word has a synonym doesn't mean a related term has one. Year, month, fortnight, week, day and hour all have an adjectival form; it just so happens that only *yearly* has a commonly used synonym, although there's *diurnal* which is used in a slightly different way to *daily* (we don't give thanks for our *diurnal* bread).

Comment: *"Each month."*  Or, *per-month*.

Comment: Merriam-Webster says that the (or a) Latin word for _monthly_ is _menstruus_, so you could argue that the monthly counterpart to _annual_ is _menstrual_. This option seems unlikely to catch on in popular usage, however.

Comment: The difference between _annual_ and _yearly_ is that one comes from Latin and the other comes from Germanic. _Monthly_ is also Germanic, but the Latin word for _monthly_ is _mensual_ (source also of _menstrual_), and that's just not a common word in English, so there's no reason to use it except to show off one's vocabulary.

Comment: The comments are right. If you insist on not using monthly just say each month. Anything else and you'll look silly.

Answer (score 13):

At least Merriam-Webster lists [**mensual**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mensual) for *monthly* as an adjective, as in *a mensual fee*.

For the adverb, that would mean you could use *mensually*, as in, *I pay mensually*.

Although I recognise the word, and the same stem is used in some other English words (like *menstruation*) I doubt the word is very commonly used or recognised (my spell checker doesn't!), so I would be careful about using this word with the expectation that people will understand you...

Comment: Shouldn't it be mensually? How many literate people, excluding the highly educated, would actually know its meaning or its existence?

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes, I forgot to mention that because I saw _monthly_, but of course, that is both an adjective and an adverb. And indeed, I doubt many people will understand this word readily.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see a better word for something repeating every month other than *monthly*, which is quite formal. Even if you somehow find one, I think there is a possibility of being misunderstood.

- Words like *bi-fortnightly* are used sometimes but even that does not equal a month. (fortnight=2 weeks)

Secondly, look at the etymology of the word *annual*

> *annus* (Latin) meaning year --> *annualis* (Late Latin) --> *annuel* (Old French) --> *annual* (Late Middle English)

- Now, one would naturally look at ***mensual*** as the 'annual' equivalent of monthly which comes from the Latin word *mensis* meaning 'month'.

But you need to be careful as the word *mensual* is usually comprehended as *menstrual* (relating to the menses or menstruation), which also has the same root word *mensis*.

Comment: `is usually comprehended as menstrual` *Usually*? Retracting my upvote because I doubt that anyone actually uses the term "mensual" to mean menstruation or period.

Comment: @Mari-LouA https://books.google.com/books?id=vFkVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA224&dq=mensual+cycle&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRl6rhyJfgAhXE2ywKHeWnDroQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=mensual%20cycle&f=false

Comment: @michael.hor257k OK, *rarely*, but the source you quote from is dated 1877 and I am talking about *today*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's just the first I found (it's difficult to weed out the results in Spanish).

Comment: @michael.hor257k well, good luck with finding the second, and the third examples which date back to the late 20th century (1980s) ;)

Comment: @Mari-LouA 1980 good enough for you? https://books.google.com/books?id=olYlAQAAIAAJ&q=%22mensual+cycle%22&dq=%22mensual+cycle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_-K6k05fgAhXCKywKHRjRAWk4ChDoAQgoMAA I have later too, but the links don't work.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A ..I never said anyone would 'use' the term mensual to mean menstruation. If you read again carefully the word I used is **'comprehend'**. What I meant is: a majority of the **listeners/readers** would quickly relate _mensual_ with _menstrual_. Cheers!

Comment: I dispute that "mensual" would be used/comprehended by the **majority** of listeners/readers/speakers to signify *menstruation* or *period.* Some, yes. The majority, I highly doubt. I still prefer the simplicity and directness of your earlier answer.

Comment: @mary-lou I don't think people would _misunderstand_ 'mensual' as 'menstrual' but many (including me) would be likely to _misread_ or _mishear_ it as such. Just a point, the spell checker on this computer has marked 'mensual' as incorrect which probably says something about its familiarity.

Comment: 'is usually comprehended' - 'is easily confused with'.